# Is diamond problem with interfaces in C# possible?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

Are there architecture problems in the code below? Is the so called [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) possible with interfaces or similar issues?

```
interface IComponent
{
    void DoStuff();
}

interface ITitledComponent : IComponent
{
    string Title { get; }
}

abstract class ComponentBase : IComponent
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class MyComponent : ComponentBase, ITitledComponent
{
    public string Title => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Certainly, diamond inheritance with classes is a bad decision and this is not possible in C#. But about the interfaces I did not find information.

Comment: I'm I'm understanding right, more usually referred to as the ["diamond problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). Of course, not a concern with pure interfaces since they don't have implementations.

Comment: It was called "diamond problem". Sorry for term mistake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Comment: The diamond problem is about classes not interfaces, you can't have it in C# cause you can't inherit more than 1 class

Comment: @R.Savelyev: at first look, you don't need to inherit `ITitledComponent` from `IComponent`. Is there any reason to do so?

Comment: **If** both `ITitledComponent` and `ComponentBase` offered *implementations* of `DoStuff` from `IComponent` and `MyComponent` didn't, that would be the diamond problem. But since interfaces cannot supply implementations, it's not the diamond problem. Even when default implementations for interfaces make an appearance (possibly in c# 8), it's not going to produce the diamond problem .

Comment: @Dennis, I have resulted the simplified structure of components in my code. Components should be built into the tree and the declaration of an abstract class looks like: abstract class ComponentBase<T> : IComponent where T : IComponent { void AttachTo( T parent ) { ... } }. For example, MyComponent can be attached only to ITitledComponent and is ITitledComponent itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to produce a diamond problem with C#, because you can only ever inherit from one class. Interfaces are not inherited, but implemented. So the actual problem for the compiler and coder, having two implementations of a method and not knowing which to pick for a specific class can never happen.